# GTK FileChooserDialog select files AND folders (Vala)

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

Is there any way to make the FileChooserDialog to select both files and folders?

I know there are the FileChooserAction OPEN and SELECT_FOLDER but they are exclusive.

PD: I dont't want two buttons, I already know how to do this. What I want is to get the routes of all selected elements (both files and folders) with the same button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The File chooser action is different from what you want. I think you are after the [**`set_select_multiple ()`**](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.FileChooser.set_select_multiple.html) method or the [**`select_multiple`**](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.FileChooser.select_multiple.html) property (both inherited from the Gtk.FileChooser interface).

Then you can use the methods [**`get_filenames ()`**](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.FileChooser.get_filenames.html) or [**`get_uris ()`**](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.FileChooser.get_uris.html), depending on your needs.

The default GtkFileChooserDialog only allows you to select folders and files if you are on the Recent "tab" but as soon as you use a normal folder it won't let you do that.

In order to achieve that you must use Gtk.FileChooserWidget by composing a solution or creating a new widget (eg. subclassing Gtk.FileChooserWidget or Gtk.Dialog).

I've created a simple example that will work as you want and that you can easily change to suit your needs.

The following code is based on [Valadoc.org](https://valadoc.org) Gtk.[FileChooserWidget](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.FileChooserWidget.html) page, which does what you are asking:

```
public class Application : Gtk.Window {
    public Application () {
        // Prepare Gtk.Window:
        this.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

        // VBox:
        Gtk.Box vbox = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 5);
        this.add (vbox);

        // HeaderBar:
        Gtk.HeaderBar hbar = new Gtk.HeaderBar ();
        hbar.set_title ("MyFileChooser");
        hbar.set_subtitle ("Select Files and Folders");

        // HeaderBar Buttons
        Gtk.Button cancel = new Gtk.Button.with_label ("Cancel");
        Gtk.Button select = new Gtk.Button.with_label ("Select");

        hbar.pack_start (cancel);
        hbar.pack_end (select);

        this.set_titlebar (hbar);

        // Add a chooser:
        Gtk.FileChooserWidget chooser = new Gtk.FileChooserWidget (Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN);
        vbox.pack_start (chooser, true, true, 0);

        // Multiple files can be selected:
        chooser.select_multiple = true;

        // Add a preview widget:
        Gtk.Image preview_area = new Gtk.Image ();
        chooser.set_preview_widget (preview_area);
        chooser.update_preview.connect (() => {
            string uri = chooser.get_preview_uri ();
            // We only display local files:
            if (uri.has_prefix ("file://") == true) {
                try {
                    Gdk.Pixbuf pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf.from_file (uri.substring (7));
                    Gdk.Pixbuf scaled = pixbuf.scale_simple (150, 150, Gdk.InterpType.BILINEAR);
                    preview_area.set_from_pixbuf (scaled);
                    preview_area.show ();
                } catch (Error e) {
                    preview_area.hide ();
                }
            } else {
                    preview_area.hide ();
            }
        });

        // HBox:
        Gtk.Box hbox = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 5);
        vbox.pack_start(hbox, false, false, 0);

        // Setup buttons callbacks
        cancel.clicked.connect (() => {
            this.destroy ();
        });

        select.clicked.connect (() => {
            SList<string> uris = chooser.get_uris ();
            foreach (unowned string uri in uris) {
                stdout.printf (" %s\n", uri);
            }
            this.destroy ();
        });
    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        Application app = new Application ();
        app.show_all ();
        Gtk.main ();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Compile with:

`valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 Gtk.FileChooserDialog.vala`

After you choose select, the application will print your selection to the console:

[image: widget]

Dumps (path partially replaced with `...`):

```
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/1
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/2
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/3
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/Gtk.FileChooserDialog
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/Gtk.FileChooserDialog.vala
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/Gtk.FileChooserWidget
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/Gtk.FileChooserWidget.vala
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/img1.jpg
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/img2.jpg
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/img3.jpg
 file:///.../stackoverflow/3305/Makefile
```

Comment: This example allows me to select multiple elements in the dialog but if one of them is a folder then the "Open" button doesn't work. It only works if all the selected elements are regular files.

Comment: @bcedu I've tried and it worked but i went to check again, it failed. If in the Recent files have folders and files you are able to do so but if in a normal folder it does not work. Seems that the dialog can't be sure if you want to navigate to that folder or choose it which is kind of logic. I'll look into it...

Comment: Perfect!! Now it works!! Thanks, thanks and thanks!!!! I started to belive it wasn't possible to make the multiple select work.

Comment: @bcedu Glad to help. With the widget you are more free to use it as you need. Good luck with your projects